# Plot with seaborn after groupby command in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, pandas-groupby

I have grouped a list using pandas and I'm trying to plot follwing table with seaborn:

```
     B  
A           
bar  3  
foo  5
```

The code `sns.countplot(x='A', data=df)` does not work `(ValueError: Could not interpret input 'A')`.

I could just use `df.plot(kind='bar')` but I would like to know if it is possible to plot with seaborn.

Answer (score 3):

In this instance I think you may be missing a reset index so you can use the index.

```
 sns.countplot(x='A', data=df.reset_index())
```

Also checkout the hue parameter for grouping which may make your groupby unnecessary

```
import seaborn as sns
df = pd.DataFrame( [['A', 'B', 'A'], [1,1,1], [4,5,4]], index=['g', 'x', 'y']).T
sns.countplot(data=df, x='y', hue='g')
```

Comment: Thanks @Darren Brien.
The .reset_index() did not plot as I wanted but your expample solved my issue

Comment: I tried but i dont have enough reputation to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
sns.countplot(x='A', data=df.reset_index())
```

Seems that column A is an index.